# check if sql statement returns empty record set in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a sql statement that when it returns nothing, I wish for the package to do nothing. If my statement returns any number of rows, I want an email to be sent. How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you want to send email, if rows are present for the result set.

I would suggest you to do below steps:

1. Create an Execute SQL task and have return type as single row. Define the statement(E.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table`) to return a single row. Store the result set into a variable. E.g. `@cnt`
2. Define conditional expression in the precedence constraint to Send Email task. If there are rows(@cnt > 0), then email will be sent. Otherwise, email will not be sent.

You can read more on defining result set for ExecuteSQL task here [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/result-sets-in-the-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014)

You can read about precedence constraint expressions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms141722(v=sql.90))